# Is there a way to check localStorage variable in ngif (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I got some localstorage variables that I set when I cache something.

I want to show in an list with an ng-repeat that an item has been cached so I have to see if the item.name is in the localstorage (presumably with an ng-if on an icon element).

```
        <ion-list class="pokemonList">
            <ion-item class="item item-icon-right" ng-repeat="pokemon in pokemons | filter:search.filter" ng-click="goToPokemon(pokemon.url, pokemon.name)">
                {{pokemon.name | capitalize}}                
                <i class="icon ion-eye" ng-if="localStorage.getItem('pokemon.' + pokemon.name)"></i>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-list>
```

This obviously doesn't work, but is there any other way to make this work?

Comment: `("pokemon." + pokemon.name) in localStorage` would be better as it doesn't load the data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advise against using complicated logic in the view. Why not just handle the logic in a controller or service?

ie. in your controller, you could map a "isCached" property to each item in your "pokemons" list.

For example:

```
angular.forEach(pokemons, function (value, key) {
    var cacheItemName = 'pokemon.' + pokemon.name;
    value.isCached = localStorage.getItem(cacheItemName) || false;
    pokemons[key] = value;
});

$scope.pokemons = pokemons;
```

Then when this list is rendered in the view, you just have to do:

`<i class="icon ion-eye" ng-if="pokemon.isCached"></i>`

In fact, I would use a middle-layer like a custom service named `CacheService` to handle saving and reading data from localStorage, because that will make it easier at a future date to swap localStorage for any different storage medium.

P.S. the plural form of Pokemon is Pokemon :P Maybe you can rename it `pokemonItem in pokemonList`.